# How to place an icon next to the last word of the first line in a Flutter Row?

Tags: flutter

I am working with a Flutter Row whose children are a text and an icon. The text is too long to fit in a single row, and the icon is placed to the left of the Row. I want the icon to be placed **next to the last word of the first line, or the longest line of the text**, and not be separated.

This is how I'm approaching it: I'm using a Flexible widget. I prefer not to use textOverflow because I want the text to remain fully visible. What I'm aiming for is to ensure the icon consistently stays beside the text. Please note that the text is dynamic; the one in the image is just an example.

```
Row(
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Text(
                            'asdh ksajdh aksdjhaskdjhas dkasjdh d peodnnasjdu',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.account_balance_sharp,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

[image]

My goal is to have the icon placed directly beside the next to the last word of the first line, or the longest line, eliminating the highlighted red space completely

Answer (score 1):

You can simply wrap the Text in a SizedBox with a fixed width and overflow: TextOverflow.visible.

```
Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 300,
                          child: Text(
                            'asdh ksajdh aksdjh askdjhas dka  sjdh dd fdsf thdgfg vxbvxb xfbxfgc xfgdfg xfgdf dfg dfjff dfsd dfsfg dfd',
                            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.account_balance_sharp,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
```

[image: Output]

Comment: If the screen size is less than 300, a renderOverflow error occurs. I usually don't like to use fixed width values that way.

Answer (score 0):

The above problem is because the Text widget wraps lines word by word.
If you cut the text character by character and wrap it using Wrap, it will be cut character by character and the space on the right side of the Text widget will be removed.

```
Row(
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Wrap(
            children: 'asdh ksajdh aksdjhaskdjhas dkasjdh d peodnnasjdu'
                .split('')
                .map((char) => Text(char))
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.account_balance_sharp,
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I didn't make myself clear, but I want the icon to be next to the last word of the first line.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: @devblock I update my answer

Comment: When i traid your answer i have this error: The argument type 'Iterable<InvalidType>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'.

Comment: @devblock I was late in answering the question due to urgent business. The error was caused by missing a parenthesis in map. It was modified by adding one more parenthesis after ```Text(char)```.

Comment: I am concerned about what implications it may have to modify that behavior. I mean, cutting the words letter by letter. It may cause the actual words or text to not look easy to read as they may break off at any letter.

Comment: @devblock If you don't want your words to be truncated, using Flexible is not the right way to go. This is because Flexible does not change size based on the text inside, but rather depends on the screen size and widgets. The only way is to calculate the text length and set the widget's size variably.

Answer (score 0):

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    children: [
      TextSpan(text: 'gsdfgfgsdgsdffdgsdfgsdf gfdgsdfgsdf dfsgdsfgsdfg gfdsdgfgsd'),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Icon(Icons.account_balance_sharp),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Output:

[image]